# Prove that a polynomial has real roots when $\lim p(x_n)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Given $p:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ polynomial nonconstant, $b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(x_n)$ such  that $\lim p(x_n)=b$, prove that $(x_n)$ is bounded and the adhesion values set is not empty and contained in $p^{-1}(b)$. In particular, if $b=0$, $p$ has a real root.

Answer (score 1):

If $(x_n)$ is not bounded, it has a subsequence $x_{n_k} \to \pm\infty$. Then clearly $|p(x_{n_k})| \to \infty$, which contradicts the fact that $p(x_{n_k})$ converges to $b$.

So $(x_n)$ is bounded, hence has a converging subsequence. By continuity $p(x)=b$ holds for the limit $x$ of any converging subsequence.